# How to add dialog box at tool bar button click in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, button, toolbar, dialog

I am working on project where I have to add a dialog box on the click of tool bar button in such a manner when user click on the that a dialog box open with three buttons.

For Example if user click on share button then a dialog box open (pointing to that button) containing three buttons facebook, twitter, email.

Please be sure that I dnt want to use action sheet.

Please provide any sample code or any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a viewcontroller object with three desired buttons on its view. And then On the viewcontroller where you're currently on you can call presentModalViewController:animated method. Like:

```
MyModalViewController *modalController=[[MyModalViewController alloc]init];
....... then whereever you touch up the tool bar button you can say:
[self presentModalViewController:modalController animated:YES];
```

But you should not forget to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated at some point(probably write this inside a button touchupinside target action method) on the dialog box to avoid having the modal view stuck on the screen forever. :)